# app.use in express is causing error when connecting to a model and route

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

I am setting my routes and models in the app.js page.  I am using **app.use**  several times.  However when I reference my model and route like so

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
```

I am getting the error

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a
            ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
```

Any reference I give to  **'/api'**  is giving me an error with app.use.  I am following the John Papa style guide.  Some of my code on express is very similar.  Seems to work fine in the hot towel generator but now working for me now.  Wondering if it could be a different issue or if I am missing something specific.

I have required my models

```
var BeerList = require('./models/IBU');
var Beer = require('./models/beerName');
```

Here are the dependencies in my package.json  Nothing out of the ordinary

```
"body-parser": "^1.8.2",
"express": "^4.12.2",
"express-session": "^1.11.3",
"mongoose": "^4.1.11",
"morgan": "^1.1.1",
"serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different way. Towards the top of the file do:

```
var routes = require('./routes/api');
```

Then put this towards the bottom.  It might be a location problem, as assigning routes should always go below other app.use's

```
app.use('/api', routes);
```